# Can a gRPC server can be a client for another gRPC client?

Tags: json, http, protocol-buffers, grpc

I am new to gRPC and currently working on making a message forwarding gRPC service.

Currently my gRPC service, written in Go, transforms HTTP/JSON into protobuf and I am wondering if I can call a client call of another gRPC service in my current gRPC service, so that it basically can work as translate-and-forward service.

Is it possible to do this?

Thanks a ton in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Using `protoc` tool you can automatically generate `server` interface, the implementation is up to you.

In your implementation code you can call other services, the only requirement it to accept input arguments and return structure as defined in interface.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can definitely do that. That's the way to build more complicated systems - System A calls System B which calls System C, and they're all written with gRPC/protobuffers.

Where you might have issues is making a generic forwarder. AFAIK you will most likely have to just hardcode the translation from the HTTP frontend to calls to a gRPC service.

Comment: Thanks Horia! I think I will use grpc-gateway for the translation tho.